# tips and tricks film mixing

Tags: film

Does anyone know where i can find tips and tricks about film mixing: track-layout, using compression or not on dialogue-mix, plugins etc.

Comment: can you somehow specify your question, because film mixing is a complex process with lots of different aspects and demands. so any general answer will probably fail sooner or later.

Comment: I completely agree with the aforementioned comment. There is a wealth of information on here in previously asked questions. Sometimes in the comments. They are sometimes difficult to dig up, but they can be found. Good luck in your search.

Comment: as far as 'where' goes, I'd suspect most people learning to mix films do so by sitting in with experienced film mixers....

Answer (score 2):

Sitting with an experienced mixer, is the best way to learn.
I am a re-recording mixer, and had been mixing for a couple of years solo.
I was hired by another studio, and the first year I wasters, I was teamed up o mix SFx with a Diakog mixer. I leant that year how little I knew about mixing dialog properly. And it was an invaluable year. What I learnt by mixing with the experienced mixer, helped me enormously when I moved to LA.

Answer (score 1):

This is super-old news, but there's a really superb book from Mix called "Sound for Picture" that's full of articles and interviews. It covers all elements of sound from a bunch of enormous films and the biggest names in the industry. A really inspiring read that has a bunch of tips and tricks as well. My copy is from 2000, so it still contains a lot of pre-ProTools stuff, but that sure doesn't make it useless.

Fantastic book.

Otherwise, I think @Tim Prebble is right... sit with a mixer! Combine that with a lot of listening to soundtracks and some good reading and, for me, that's the magic cocktail.